# document.getElementById().value average

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code in php document:

```
var product=0;
function add(){
    if (product<10) {
     product++;
    }
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = product;
    document.getElementById('display1').value = product;

}
function rem(){
    if (product>1){
     --product;
    }
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = product;
    document.getElementById('display1').value = product;

}

var place=0;
function addplace(){
    if (place<10) {
     place++;
    }
    document.getElementById('display_place').innerHTML = place;
    document.getElementById('display_place1').value = place;

}
function remplace(){
    if (place>1){
     --place;
    }
    document.getElementById('display_place').innerHTML = place;
    document.getElementById('display_place1').value = place;

}
```

Then I have this html code to display vars:

```
<button style="background-image: url('files/arrow_down.png');" type="button" onClick="rem()"></button>
<button style="background-image: url('files/arrow_up.png');" type="button" onClick="add()"></button>

<div id="display" name="product">
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(product);</script>
</div>/10</div>
<input type="hidden" id="display1" name="display1">

<button style="background-image: url('files/arrow_down.png');" type="button" onClick="remplace()"></button>
<button style="background-image: url('files/arrow_up.png');" type="button" onClick="addplace()"></button>

<div id="display_place">
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(place);</script>
</div>/10</div>
<input type="hidden" id="display_place1" name="display_place1">
```

So, I display "product" var in "display" div and send the value from "display1" div through form.

Same with "place" var, with "display_place" div and "display_place1".

Now, I need to display this value:

(product + place)/2

Can someone suggest how can I do this?
I'm not familiar with JS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you want to display that value??
you can simply make a div named `product_place` and input field named `product_place1` and use this code:

```
function show(){      
    document.getElementById('product_place').innerHTML = (product + place)/2;
    document.getElementById('product_place1').value = (product + place)/2;
}
```

The HTML part would be like this:

```
<button type="button" onClick="show()">show</button>

<div id="product_place">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write((product + place)/2);
</script>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="product_place1" name="product_place1">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Actually I want to show that value on the same page but to be dynamic. So, when I click "add" button, this value to be changed automatically

Comment: you can call this function `show()` just before } bracket in your all 4 functions i.e. add, rem, addplace. remplace...